# Arduino Uno to Arduino Uno Word.doc file transfer

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, spi, sd-card

I have written a 2 sets of code for the transmitter and receiver section. I am trying to send a word document file from 1 arduino uno to the next arduino uno through serial TX and RX. The file is initially loaded into a micro sd card module at the transmitter section. I would like to transfer that file to the receiver section's sd card module. I am able to receive an empty word document at the receiver section. There is no information in the document. I would like some help with this. I will attach the transmitter and receiver code below.

Transmitter code:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>

File fileIn;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial){
    ; //  wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if(!SD.begin(4)){
    Serial.println(F("Initialization failed!"));
    return;
  } 
  Serial.println("Initialization done.");
  if(!SD.exists("student.txt")){
    fileIn = SD.open("student.txt", FILE_WRITE);
    fileIn.println(F("abc.txt"));
  }
  fileIn = SD.open("student.txt", FILE_READ);

  while(fileIn.available()){
    Serial.write(fileIn);
  }
  delay(1000);
  fileIn.close();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Receiver code:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>

File fileOut;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial){
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if(!SD.begin(4)){
    Serial.println(F("Initialization failed!"));
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("Initialization done.");
  if(SD.exists("student2.txt")){
    SD.remove("student2.txt");
  }
  fileOut = SD.open("student2.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  while(fileOut.available()){
    Serial.write(fileOut);  
  }
  delay(1000);
  fileOut.close();
  Serial.println("It worked!");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  while(fileOut.available()){
    Serial.write(fileOut);  
  }
```

This doesn't quite do what you think it does.

Instead you should send the file length first and then do:

```
for(unsigned long size = 0; i< fileLength; i++){
    Serial.write(fileOut.read());  
}
```

You should also investigate some kind of rate limiting to avoid overwhelming the reciever and having to drop some bytes.

Comment: Is it possible to read the line and take that as a file length in the 1st arduino and how would I implement this with the receiver arduino?

Comment: File has a size() member function. And just send 4 bytes with the length before you send the rest of the file. on the recieve side the first 4 bytes read will be the size of the file you will be recieving.